# Shift + Backspace won't work on Vim for Windows

Tags: windows, vim

Before you mark this question as a double, hear me out because I've looked around and I can't find anything that'll fix my issue.

In Vim for Windows (accessed through Powershell running from CMD in a console), backspace works fine. Pressing Shift (or Ctrl) + Backspace prints a weird looking I to the screen and presses Ctrl+C.

Using :set  to see what the keycode for the backspace is on my Vim yields this: "Î^Cx". This makes sense considering the behavior described above. The interesting part is that this keycode obviously is for the normal backspace key. My problem however, doesn't appear when pressing backspace normally, which doesn't make sense to me considering that the normal keycode is this weird collection of characters. It only appears when combining backspace with the shift key.

I don't understand why the backspace key doesn't send ^H or ^?. I've heard that those two options are popular. I assume my terminal is messing this up in some way, but I don't understand why it would be sending a different keycode for backspace when the shift key is pressed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect Shift+Backspace to do? Do you have the same issue in other terminal emulators? Other shells?

Comment: @romainl The interesting part is that I don't have the same issue anywhere else. It works fine when SSHing to my linux machine from powershell and it works fine when I normally do it in the terminal. It even works fine in other text editors like micro. I don't know why vim doesn't work.

Comment: And I have no idea what "works" means for you because `Shift+Backspace` is not supposed to do anything in Vim, where it is indistinguishable from `Backspace`. So I'm asking again, a bit differently: why are you pressing `Shift+Backspace` to begin with? As for the other question, if you have the desired behaviour in other contexts, then it means that the undesired behaviour is caused by something in your current context and the right course of action is to bisect your setup. Also, it is pretty obvious that, in this specific context, Vim is receiving unexpected input.

Comment: @romainl I use Shift+Backspace a lot when I'm setting up defines in C++. I just hold down shift and type something, and if I make a mistake, I don't remove my finger from shift before deleting the thing that was wrong. This causes a weird looking I to be added to the line, which is very annoying.

Comment: @romainl Everyone presses Shift+Backspace when they want to delete a capital letter they just typed. It's quite counterintuitive to have to release the shift key before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue like this:

```
imap Î^Cy <BS>
```

In my (Windows) terminals, `Î^Cy` is shift-backspace and `Î^Cz` is ctrl-backspace, and I have remapped them both.  If `Î^Cx` is shift-backspace in your terminal, which it seems like it is, try adding this to your vimrc file:

```
imap Î^Cx <BS>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for this. Everything works great now. I wonder why Windows chooses to send these weird combinations to the terminal instead of just the normal backspace keycodes. The fact that terminal programs can differentiate between Shift + BS and Ctrl + BS and just BS is strange as well, is the same thing possible on Linux for example? If so, how does Linux handle that?

Comment: Great to hear it worked. This was a frustrating problem for me, too. Terminals in Windows all vary slightly in their implementations, and interpretation of keyboard-input is unfortunately one of those differences. In my experience, CMD.exe, powershell, GitBash terminal, vim (windows) terminal, and Gvim all give different behaviour for certain keys.  Linux and MacOS have a native BASH terminal, so there doesn't need to be different emulations made at different times by different people for different purposes. One shell, one standard (one of the reasons developers tend to prefer unix systems).

Comment: When I press Shift+Backspace in my keyboard I get `Îy`. I tried adding `imap Îy <BS>` in my vimrc file but it doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* this happened in your configuration, but you should be able to use `inoremap` to make it do what you want.

Interactively, you can test my idea by typing this

```
:inoremap <hit control-V><hit shift-backspace> <hit control-v><hit backspace>
```

What this will do is create a non-recursive map in insert mode for the escape sequence generated by `<shift-backspace>` to the escape sequence generated by `<backspace>`.

In my case, the result looked like

```
:inoremap ^? ^?
```

because my `<shift-backspace>` produces the same sequence as `<backspace>`, but in your case it should produce something more useful for you.

Once you've figured this out, move it to your `.vimrc` without the colon, and that will hopefully fix your issue in a lasting way.

Comment: @ I've now tried this and it doesn't work either. After hitting Ctrl + V on the keyboard, pressing shift + backspace (or just backspace) just exits command mode. I don't remember how, but I did discover what characters actually get sent when pressing backspace and shift+backspace (they were "Î^Cx"). The problem is that both shift+backspace and backspace both send these characters. I don't know how vim even knows that I pressed shift, the keycodes are identical. Even so, even if there was something to fix, vim doesn't let me finish the command because as I said, it just exits command mode.

Comment: Wow, I guess all I have to say now is that I don't understand what's going on in your configuration! Sorry, I don't think I can help you actually solve it, with what you're saying here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the same issue as me I wonder where this happens in Windows Powershell but doesn't happen in `gvim` or when you run `vim` under `cmd`. If so I think the other responders are correct that vim does nothing different with shift+BS than BS but the Powershell command running it is. It's not an answer, I don't know a way around it other than use gvim. But if you're trying to dig further I'd suggest it's Windows Powershell that's the issue (unless I'm wrong of course) rather than vim.

Comment: Answer post should contain relevant answer to the prior issue. Relevant suggestion need to included under comment section

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: You're all right this is not an answer (as clearly stated) however I don't have any SO reputation so can't comment and I spent a lot of time debugging this problem so if anyone else finds the same situation this may help. If someone can move it to a comment that would be better, I cannot.

Comment: @Strottos then delete it so it doesn't keep getting downvoted and you lose even more reputation

Comment: @user32882 Would you like to move it to a comment for me and then I'll happily do so? I believe my information to be useful, this is the only method I have of potentially saving someone the hours I spent debugging this problem at this time. If you'll forgive me being quite frank, I'd rather get downvoted on SO when I've tried to be helpful with the best of intentions than have someone that could have made use of this information but it wasn't available.

Comment: @Strottos sorry, I don't have the privileges to move questions to comments (I don't believe anyone does, really). You an do whatever you like, I was just making a suggestion.

Comment: OK, thanks anyway though. And yes fair enough, no worries :)